# IIS ApplicationInitialization doesn't call initializationPage on one of the servers

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis, iis-8

I setup applicationinitialization for our web app by following up https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

the below is my changes in `web.config`

```
<applicationInitialization   doAppInitAfterRestart="true"   skipManagedModules="true"   remapManagedRequestsTo="init.html">
  <add initializationPage="/warmup/init" hostName="phoenix"/>
</applicationInitialization>
```

It's working find on my local (win10) and 2 other environment for `dev` and `staging` (both win2012) but not working on `QA` environment (win2012).

on `QA` environment I see `init.html` on screen when app poll recycles, but `initializationPage` is not called at all.

`startMode` of app poll is `AlwayRunning`

`Preload Enabled` is `true` on webapp,

`Idle Time-out` is 0 on app pool

`Regular Time Interval (minutes)` is 0 on app pool

I checked windows event logs no related logs are there.

Any other settings to check?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Application Initialization feature installed?  The options apparently exist even if the feature is not installed on the Windows system.  I was having the same issue and had to go to Windows Features and select "Application Initialization" from the IIS feature options to get it working.